# Trying to validate user input to make sure it is one of two characters

Tags: c++

I am starting to learn the C++ syntax and I am attempting to validate user input in a program I am writing. Here is what i try to do:

```
string genderC;
cout << "Enter 'm' for male and 'f' for female:" << endl;
cin >> genderC;
while( !(cin >> genderC) || genderC != 'f'|| genderC != 'm') {
    cout << "Bad input\nEnter 'm' for male and 'f' for female:" << endl;
    cin.clear();
}
//...
```

it gives me the following error:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>,     allocator<char> >') and 'int')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use dobcle quites for string

Comment: Bartender I'll have what @Jasen is having!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this

```
genderC != 'f'|| genderC != 'm'
```

to this:

```
genderC != "f" || genderC != "m"
```

The `genderC` is a `string` and a `string` is a sequence of characters between two `"`. If `genderC` was a `char`, you wouldn't had any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a string to a char. char is an integer type which is why you get the error message
saying that you can't compare a string to an int.

`'f'` and `'m'` are of type `char` while `genderC` has type `std::string`.

So you have two options:

1. Take input of type char
2. Compare genderC to `"f"` and `"m"` (which are strings) instead

Answer (score 0):

The `genderC` variable is of type "string" and you are comparing it with 'f' and 'm' which are of type "char" due to the single quotes.

Your problem should be fixed if you rewrite your while loop like this:

```
while( !(cin >> genderC) || genderC != "f" || genderC != "m") {
```

Due to the double quotes, "f" and "m" are of type "char*" which can be compared with "string".

Note that the compiler is referring to those two literal "char" type as "int" because char is, in fact, an 8-bit integer.